# JQuery apply css function at beginning of event, revert at end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that takes a noticeable time to execute, and would like to apply a css change so that the user knows the site is loading. I have a change function linked to a drop down filter which sorts through data on the page.

```
$("#job_group").change(function() {
        console.log("Change");
        $("#displayTable").css("opacity", "0.5"); // gray out the table while this is executing
        // Some code that executes
        showResults();
        $("#displayTable").css("opacity", "1"); // put it back to normal once its done
        console.log("All done");
});
```

The console logs are outputting in the console with the behavior I am trying to do, but the first css change essentially gets ignored because it is changing and immediately reverting back even though the code is still taking time to execute.

Ultimately, what should happen is:

- Change Function executes
- Make table opaque
- Filter out results
- Revert table to normal opacity

**EDIT**

Show Results gets the number of results

```
function showResults() {
        let count = 0;
        $(".jd-row").each(function() {
        if($(this).css("display") !== "none" && !$(this).hasClass("jd-row-expand")) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    $("#results").html(count + "");
}
```

Comment: How you approach this depends entirely on the work `showResults()` is doing, and whether it's async or not.

Comment: Okay I updated to show this function

Comment: *"... even though the code is still taking time to execute"* how do you determine that? Unless you have thousands of rows, `showResults()` should not run for more than a few ms. Are you talking about transitions/animations?

Comment: @rileyjsumner thanks for updating, I added an answer for you below

Comment: @freedomn-m `showResults()` is not the function that is taking time, I hid code since its long and not relevant to the solution

Comment: Surely you can work out that you move the code that **does take the time** into the setTimeout?  (I deleted my comment 3 seconds after adding it as it was the same as Rory's answer)

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I understand this thank you

Answer (score 2):

Given that the logic in `showResults()` is synchronous you need to put it in a timeout so that JS has time to update the DOM before the thread is blocked by the `each()` loop. You need to reset the opacity within this timeout as well. Try this:

```js
$("#job_group").change(function() {
  var $table = $("#displayTable").css("opacity", "0.5");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showResults();
    $table.css("opacity", "1");
  }, 50);     
});
```

However, it's worth stating that a long-running synchronous operation is far from ideal. I'd suggest making the logic async if possible. Better still, move the filtering server side and use AJAX.